# How to set image upload location in HtmlEditorExtender and enabling Sanitization stops debugging after referencing 3 dlls and editing web.config?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Today I added HtmlEditorExtender to my asp.net web application everything works fine but i am facing two major problems in this:
1. How can i set image upload location where the image will be uploaded by HtmlEditorExtender.
2. I am not able to enable AntiXSS Sanitizer Provider for this HtmlEditorExtender i followed the methods on this page
[asp.net ajax page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx)

but when i put this code in Web.config

```
<sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider" 
        type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.
          AntiXssSanitizerProvider"></add>
    </providers>
</sanitizer>
```

this underlines `<sanitizer>` tag and on debugging it asks me to provide an Sanitizer.cs file and tells that 
Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.AntiXssSanitizerProvider'. (C:\Users\saurav\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\sauravtopnet\sauravtopnet\web.config line 56)
Locating source for 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {79 93 7c d3 c7 ff b7 88 f af 76 3c 18 24 66 19}
The file 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs'.

I should tell you that in
c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\HtmlEditorExtender\HtmlEditorExtender.cs
Stephen is not any user on my system than why debugger is looking for this path.

I added these two lines to my code behind page

```
using AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer;
using Microsoft.Security.Application;
```

this is my ajax code

```
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender
    ID="hee" EnableSanitization="true"
    TargetControlID="txtComments"
    Runat="server" >
    <Toolbar> 
            <ajaxToolkit:Undo />
            <ajaxToolkit:Redo />
            <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
            <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
            <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
            <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
            <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
            <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
            <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
            <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
            <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
            <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
            <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
            <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
            <ajaxToolkit:SelectAll />
            <ajaxToolkit:UnSelect />
            <ajaxToolkit:Delete />
            <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
            <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
            <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
            <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
            <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
            <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
            <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
            <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
            <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
            <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
            <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
            <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
        </Toolbar>
    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

this is my reference

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

and i already downloaded and added all three .dlls.

Comment: Long time ago now but Ive just as at the date of this post done the same and it seems AntiXSS Sanitizer Provider is no longer being used despite what it says on the Ajax Toolkit Sample site dues to a series of incompatabilities. 

Instead I had to use:  <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
            </providers>
        </sanitizer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very difficult task to configure Ajax HtmlEditorExtender but this [link : http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/05/01/ajax-control-toolkit-may-2012-release.aspx](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/05/01/ajax-control-toolkit-may-2012-release.aspx) will guide you how to set image upload path and other related settings

Next problem was how to setup sanitizer to protect you from XSS attacks. Actually the recommended sanitizer provider doesn't work correctly. Look what i did for that

1. Download AntiXSS.4.2.1 from Microsoft CodePlex or through NuGet
2. Now extract zip file you will get two .dlls AntiXSSLibrary.dll and HtmlSanitizationLibrary.dll add your project References to these two .dlls
3. Now add `using Microsoft.Security.Application;` to your code behind page.
4. Now Use the code below on click event of any button through which you want to get and show your input in htmleditor.

Here txteditor is the the id of the asp:textbox which is linked with your htmleditor. Input of any textbox is always encoded by .net framework for security so first decoded input html text then replaced `<br>` tag with my own word then i forwarded the input to sanitizer that will remove any XSS attack code but unfortunately it also removes html codes like `<br>, <img src=""/> or <a href=""></a>` thats why i replaced the `<br>` tag here now decode sanitized html again and replace your words with corresponding tags. Now you can show your html anywhere like i shown in div1. I think these info. can help you in your further steps.

```
String x = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txteditor.Text).Replace("<br>", "rrrbbbbrbrbrbrbr"); 
String y = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(x); 
div1.InnerHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(y).Replace("rrrbbbbrbrbrbrbr", "<br>"); 
txteditor.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(y).Replace("rrrbbbbrbrbrbrbr", "<br>");
```

Make default sanitizer to false like this:

```
    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="ajaxeditor" OnImageUploadComplete="ajaxFileUpload_OnUploadComplete" TargetControlID="txteditor" DisplaySourceTab="false" EnableSanitization="false" Runat="server" >
```

No need to configure anything in web.config and no need to add those 3 .dlls which are recommended on www.asp.net

Comment: Hey user, pretty thanks for sharing this. I will figure out the sanitizer stuff the next days. I've seen the 'disable sanitizing' though as far as I understood it (but it was just a quick read over) is not really a solution for me. As far as I remember Stephen even mentions on his page that this is just for debugging and should never ever go live. Though, if you are including the AntiXSS on your own, this may work then because you take care of this all 'on your own'. I will give it a try, thanks for sharing again :)

Answer (score 4):

The first part you got right:

```
<configsections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web">
    <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection,  AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configsections>
```

In your `system.web`:

```
<system.web>
    <sanitizer defaultProvider="AntiXssSanitizerProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="AntiXssSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" />
        </providers>
      </sanitizer>
</system.web>
```

The html:

```
 <asp:Textbox ID="replyBody" Height="400px" Width="892px" runat="server" TextMode ="MultiLine"  />
 <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="replyBody_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" OnImageUploadComplete="saveFile"  ClientIDMode="AutoID" EnableSanitization="true"  TargetControlID="replyBody">
 <Toolbar>
     <ajaxToolkit:Bold />
     <ajaxToolkit:Italic />
     <ajaxToolkit:Underline />
     <ajaxToolkit:StrikeThrough />
     <ajaxToolkit:Subscript />
     <ajaxToolkit:Superscript />
     <ajaxToolkit:JustifyLeft />
     <ajaxToolkit:JustifyCenter />
     <ajaxToolkit:JustifyRight />
     <ajaxToolkit:JustifyFull />
     <ajaxToolkit:InsertOrderedList />
     <ajaxToolkit:InsertUnorderedList />
     <ajaxToolkit:CreateLink />
     <ajaxToolkit:UnLink />
     <ajaxToolkit:RemoveFormat />
     <ajaxToolkit:Cut />
     <ajaxToolkit:Copy />
     <ajaxToolkit:Paste />
     <ajaxToolkit:BackgroundColorSelector />
     <ajaxToolkit:ForeColorSelector />
     <ajaxToolkit:FontNameSelector />
     <ajaxToolkit:FontSizeSelector />
     <ajaxToolkit:Indent />
     <ajaxToolkit:Outdent />
     <ajaxToolkit:InsertHorizontalRule />
     <ajaxToolkit:HorizontalSeparator />
     <ajaxToolkit:InsertImage />
 </Toolbar>
 </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

As for setting the image location, its passed in the `AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs`

The properties are `e.FileName` to retrieve the file name and `e.postedUrl` to tell the control where you uploaded it and can be done as depicted below:

```
protected void saveFile(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string fullPath = "/Images/Upload_test/"+ e.FileName;

    // Save your File
    replyBody_HtmlEditorExtender.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fullPath));

    // Tells the HtmlEditorExtender where the file is otherwise it will render as: <img src="" />
    e.PostedUrl = fullPath;
}
```

That worked quite well for me.

Comment: thanx for sharing this, this will surely help in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same problem and I was messing around with that for days.

At least I had first success right now.
I was following this guide:
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/getting-started/using-ajax-control-toolkit-controls-and-control-extenders-cs

I'm writing down the steps which are the most important ones for me:

- Create a Web Forms project
- Installation with NuGet or manually doesn't matter (I installed it via NuGet and linked the toolbox entry to the dll in the packages-folder of my project)
- I didn't fix anything in the web.config of my project (though I need to have a look at the sanitizing stuff as one of the next steps)
- I use the ASP script manager, not the ajax control toolkit one

So here is my snippet which actually works for me (at least for now, seeing anything which doesn't depend on Stephens' pc is success to me right now ^^)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="webforms._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>hey ho</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      hello world!
    </div>
    <div>
      second div
      <br/>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      </asp:ScriptManager>
      <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, I solved all my problems related to this question, can you tell me what are the problems you are facing now I will try to give you solution of that. thanx for helping.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will ask if I have any questions, but after this break through things actually seem to look a little bit better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting this to false helped me in my case, `EnableSanitization="false"`.

Comment: But that will make my HTML Editor as well as my site open for Cross Site Scripting, so i need to sanitize my html inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

As bully suggested above, you will need the script manager. However you will need the ajax tool kit script manager. One other thing I found was you need to place the correct settings in the web.config in order to upload files correctly. Both settings are required "security" and "handlers".

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Upload images in htmlediterextender code

```
    protected void htmleditorextender_ImageUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
       {
           string fullpath = Server.MapPath("~/images/") + e.FileName;

           editor_extender.AjaxFileUpload.SaveAs(fullpath);

           e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/images/" + e.FileName);
       }
```