# HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-sanitizing

my problem is , i am trying to use HTML Extended Editor. I installed ajaxcontrooltoolkit. So far so good, the control toolkit is working fine but i need to sanitize . so i downloaded the htmlagilitypack and use it like this : (also added EnableSanitization = "true" on control)

added in webconfig :

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web">
<section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
</sectionGroup>
```

and :

```
<sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
  </providers>
</sanitizer>
```

but when i load my page with the ajaxcontrool it shows the following error :

Could not load type 'AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider'

I have all the dlls referenced (AjaxControolToolkit,HtmlAgilityPack,SanitizersProviders). I read the post [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376700/how-to-set-image-upload-location-in-htmleditorextender-and-enabling-sanitization) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022493/could-not-load-type-ajaxcontroltoolkit-sanitizer-antixsssanitizerprovider) but didn't helped me. What can i do? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. It seems it was a problem of dll versions, sanitizersProviders that i had wasn't compatible with HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6, but with 1.4.0, and I had to guess that because no error other that the one I mentioned appeared.